# Material UI searchbar - Using hooks to set state of a query

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I am trying to implement a search bar using the component:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-search-bar

My current code is:

```
function Searchbar() {

  const [finalQuery, setQuery] = useState("");


    return(
        <SearchBar              
            onChange={(event) => console.log(event)}
            onRequestSearch={() => setQuery(#Update the state so that it reflects the query the user wrote)}
            style={{
                marginTop: 200,
                marginLeft: 'auto',
                marginRight: 'auto',
                maxWidth: 800,
                }}
        />
    )
}
```

It is not clear to me how I can pass to `setQuery` the value of the final search (when user presses enter) so that the state `finalQuery` is updated.

If for example I do:

```
onRequestSearch={() => setQuery(console.log("trytry"))}
```

When I press enter, in console I get `trytry` so I am assuming that the state of `finalQuery` is correctly updated. But how can I do it dynamically?

The final query then will be sent to an API.

Answer (score 1):

onChange is called every time the text changes so the right place to update your query is in onChange

```
return (
<SearchBar
    value={finalQuery}
    onChange={(newValue) => setQuery(newValue)}
    onRequestSearch={() => doSomethingWith(query)}
/>
)
```

Comment: Thanks. So in my case `doSomethingWith` would be to send the conent of `newValue` to my backend API?

Comment: yes, this is triggered when the search icon is clicked or on press of enter

Comment: Thanks. I also think I do not need `value={query}` if I am using hooks. I did:       `onChange={(event) => setQuery(event)}
      onRequestSearch={() => (console.log(finalQuery))}` and it seems to ouput the right value of the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to do this.

```
 <
    SearchBar
            value={finalQuery}
            onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
            onRequestSearch={() => doSomethingWith(finalQuery)}
        />
```